# Google Pageinsight LCP issue only on mobile device (Vuejs)

Tags: vue.js, optimization, google-pagespeed, google-pagespeed-insights-api

After a lot of optimization, I manage to achieve good performance (above 60) on mobile device for my vuejs website, but it does not improve my Largest Contentful Paint (LCP). it remains unchanged.

need some help so I can improve my LCP.
Thank you in advance

Comment: We need more info to help you on this. It is impossible for us to guess what is causing a high LCP time without seeing the site code. Maybe post a link to the site in the comments.

Comment: Here is the link for my website https://propertyscout.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visiting https://propertyscout.io/ for mobile on lab data LCP is 3.3 so field data will be less than that from my experience.   Following change can help you to improve further on LCP

1. Preload Key since CSS  requests are loading from different domain
2. Remove unused JS and CSS.
3. Also load Below fold css in defer mode.

Comment: Can you please elaborate #3 bit more?

Comment: Hi Ahmed, Styles that are needed below the default view port load in defer mode. More details at  https://web.dev/defer-non-critical-css/